# If E is measurable, then $\delta E$ is measurable.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Problem: If $\delta =(\delta_1,\delta_2,\cdots,\delta_d)$ is a d-tuple of positive numbers $\delta_i>0$, and $E$ is a subset of $\mathbf{R^d}$, we define $\delta E$ by $\delta E = \{(\delta_1x_1,\delta_2x_2,\cdots)|(x_1,x_2,\cdots)\in E\}$
Prove that $\delta E$ is measurable whenever $E$ is measurable and  $m(\delta_E)= \delta_1\cdots\delta_d m(E)$. (Source:Elias Stein-Real Analysis)

My Proof: Suffice to prove $\delta E = \{(\delta_1x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_d)|(x_1,x_2,\cdots)\in E\}$. It is also clear that the result holds when $E$ is an open set( What's more, in this case $\delta E$ is also an open set). Now consider the general case: Since $E$ is measurable we know that there exists $O_n$ such that $m_*(O_n - O) \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ Since $O_n$ is open we can write it as $O_n= \cup_{i=1}^\infty Q_i$ ($Q_i$ closed cubes) With $O_n=P_1 \cup P_2$ where $P_2=\{Q_i|Q_i \in E \},P_1=\{Q_i|Q_i \not\in E \}$. Since we can split cubes thus we can let $m_*(P_1) \leq \epsilon$ thus we have $m_*(\delta O_E - \delta E) \leq m_*(\delta P_1 -\delta_E) + m_*(\delta P_2 - \delta E)$ = $m_*(\delta P_1 -\delta_E) \leq m_*(\delta P_1) \leq \epsilon$ thus $\delta E$ is measurable. We also get the inequality $m_*(\delta O_n) -\epsilon \leq m_*(\delta E) \leq m_*(\delta O_n)$ Thus let $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$, we have $m(\delta E) = m(\delta O_n)=\delta m(O_n) =\delta m(E)$

I am not sure that I use squeeze theorem in a right way. Can anyone give me some suggestions about this proof?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me offer a simpler proof of measurability. Consider the following matrix:
\begin{align*}
T\equiv\left[\begin{array}{cccc}\delta_1&0&\ldots&0\\0&\delta_2&\ldots&0\\\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\0&0&\ldots&\delta_d\end{array}\right]
\end{align*}
Since the $\delta_i$ are positive, the matrix $T$ is invertible. Then, you have that $$\delta E=\{T(x)\,|\,x\in E\}=T(E)=(T^{-1})^{-1}(E).$$
That is, $\delta E$ is the inverse image of the set $E$ under the linear (and hence measurable) map $T^{-1}:\mathbb R^d\to\mathbb R^d$. This readily implies that $\delta E$ is measurable.

Comment: WoW....... It looks so cool..........